# Display product counter only in subcategories - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello stackoverflow community.

I am trying to get functionality to display a product counter but only in subcategories. In the main categories I want to disable it.

At the moment I have been able to do this:

```
function add_product_count_view()
{
    global $wp_query;

    $category_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $category_id,
          'include_children' => true,
      ),
  ),
  'nopaging' => true,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  ));

    if (function_exists("is_shop") && $category_id != 0) {
        echo '(' .esc_html($query->post_count) . ')';
    }
}
```

and output

```
<span class="custom-home-category-counts">
       <?php do_action('count_product_title');?>
</span>
```

This way I got what I want but the counter shows the same value for each subcategory
[image: counter]

**----UPDATE----** @CBroe

It is possible that all this code is garbage. My knowledge of PHP is quite poor. Generally what I mean is, I want to disable the product counter in main categories and leave only in all subcategories.

This is the original code that renders the product counter.

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod('category_show_count', 1)) : ?>
                    <p class="is-xsmall uppercase count">
                        <?php if ($category->count > 0) {
                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', $category->count . ' ' . ($category->count > 1 ? __('Products', 'woocommerce') : __('Product', 'woocommerce')), $category);
                }
                            ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: _"This way I got what I want"_ - I don't think you actually did. Pretty sure that `11` is the count of posts in the parent category, not that of _any_ of the sub-categories. This all happens within the same page, so `$wp_query->get_queried_object()` is the same object every time your function is called - and that object is the parent category. You would need to pass the id of the current sub-category to your function, that that you can actually count the posts _in that_.

Answer (score 0):

After every custom WP_Query, you need to run `wp_reset_postdata()` to ensure that global `$post` is restored to the current post in the main query.

In your code, you can use this function as follows:

```
function add_product_count_view()
{
    global $wp_query;

    $category_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $category_id,
          'include_children' => true,
      ),
  ),
  'nopaging' => true,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  ));

    if (function_exists("is_shop") && $category_id != 0) {
        echo '(' .esc_html($query->post_count) . ')';
    }
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the main query loop

}
```

This way, the next time the query runs, it runs with new data. This can be the reason why the counter shows same value for all sub categories.

Comment: Nop, that solution didint work for me. Maybe my whole code is broken ?